# length of array of private class is not accessible

Tags: java, arrays

Please consider the following code :

```
class A {
    B[] arr = new B[10];

    private class B {}
}


class C {
    void fun(){
        A a = new A();
        Object arr = a.arr;
        Object len = a.arr.length;  // !! ERROR
    }
}
```

As I written in code. `a.arr.length;` is giving error.

I actually understand why it is happening. It is because sub class `B` is private. But still why it is happening. In class A, property `arr` was accessible, but why not it's length. Is there any explanation for this in jls or anywhere.

I just want a clear explanation for this behaviour. I know private things cannot be accessed outside of its class. But a public array could be. No matter of what type it is. And if anything is accessible outside, then its public properties should also be accessed. But here it is not happening.

**Edit :** I found that in C# it is not even possible to create an array of private class. In java if we cannot access anything, and cannot even know the length of the array of private class then what is the use of creating an array of private class.

Comment: private data can only be accessing through public method of the same class. `arr` default so is visible inside `A` but `B` is private so not. remove private from `B` it wont show any error.

Comment: What I find curious is that you can actually use the expression `a.arr[0]`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, there are many uses for an array of a private class. You can use it for internal purposes of the enclosing class. Or you can expose items in it as return values etc.

Comment: @RealSkeptic but It is giving error even when I try to get the items in it.

Comment: You tried `Object item = a.arr[0]`? Note that in your current code all members are null. You should instantiate them if you want to do something with them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic friend. I will initiate them. but what are you talking. It doesn't matter if I put values in any array or not. it should return when I use `arr[0]` if it is accessible. and the value should be null. There is no way initializing will solve problem.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. You can get access to `a.arr[0]`. You can use it if you cast it to any public type that it extends/implements. So if you had an instance of `B` in `a.arr[0]`, and you use `Object item = a.arr[0]` in `C`, you can then use `item.toString()`, for example, despite the fact that the underlying class is private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is a combination of two statements in the JLS:

1. [Item 6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) Determining accessibility:

   > An array type is accessible if and only if its element type is accessible.

   This means that if `T` is private, `T[]` is also considered private.
2. [Item 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) Array members:

   > The `public final` field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.

Remember that accessibility is determined at compile-time based on the **type of reference** you have, not on the type of the actual object!

Now, let's go into a little more elaborate example to demonstrate what this means. I added a `toString()` and a constructor to `B`.

```
class A {
    B[] arr = { new B(1), new B(2), new B(3), new B(4) };
    B plain = new B(99);

    private class B  {
        public int i;
        B(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Hidden class B(" + i + ")";
        }

    }
}
```

Now, in class C, we use:

```
A a = new A();
Object plain = a.plain;
String s = plain.toString();
```

This is legal, because `a.plain` is a visible field. `s` will contain `Hidden class B(99)`. But if you try:

```
String s = a.plain.toString(); // Compile error
```

This will not be allowed, because althogh `toString()` in `B` is public, `B` itself is private, you have no access to its members, whether public or private.

Note that we cannot access `i` in `B` despite its being public. If we use:

```
plain.i
```

Then since `i` is not a member of `Object`, you get a compile error. And if we use:

```
a.plain.i
```

Then since `a.plain` is private, you can't access its members, as we already tried.

So now we go and look at the issue of arrays. Suppose we write:

```
Object[] objArr = a.arr;
int len = objArr.length;
```

This is legal, despite the fact that `objArr` is internally `A.B[]`. We have a reference to `Object[]`, `Object` is public and so is `Object[]`. But:

```
int len = a.arr.length;
```

Gives you a compile error exactly as we got for `a.plain.toString()`. Although `length` is public in itself, you are accessing it through a reference to `A.B[]`. `A.B[]` is not accessible because `A.B` is not accessible. And therefore, because `length` is its member, you cannot access it. You simply cannot access any member of a reference type that is not visible to you, by the first rule above.

It is interesting to note that the following **is** legal:

```
Object firstItem = a.arr[0];
```

We can use the expression `a.arr[0]` because it is not considered an attempt to access a member of the array. The elements of the array are not considered to be members in it. `a.arr[0]` is simply an expression on an array reference that resolves to type `A.B`. There is no problem with such an expression as long as we don't try to access members of the item.

```
firstItem.toString() // Good
a.arr[0].toString()  // Bad
```

**Summary**

- It's OK to get hold to a reference to a private type, provided you cast it to some public supertype.
- It's OK to get a specific item in an array of a private type. Indexing the array is not considered "accessing a member", it's just an expression on a reference that gives you a reference to its member type. Which you'll need to cast to something public in order to use.
- It's not OK to try accessing a member with a given reference to a private type, even if the member is public. This includes the `length` of an array.
- It's OK to access that public member through a cast to a supertype if it's available in that supertype. `length` is available in `Object []` so you can get it through that.
- It's not possible to access a public member of a private type that doesn't exist in an accessible supertype.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
 class A {
    B[] arr = new B[10];

    public int getArrayLength()
    {
        return arr.length;
    }
    private class B {}
}


class C {
    void fun(){
        A a = new A();
        Object arr = a.arr;
        //Object isn't type safe
        //Object len = a.getArrayLength();
        int len = a.getArrayLength();
    }
}
```

According to [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> At the member level, you can also use the public modifier or no modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with the same meaning. For members, there are two additional access modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Comment: The post is not a problem. I am not looking for solution. But an expanation. What I wanted to do could be done in many ways. But question is the behaviour of the code I presented.

Comment: in the link to JavaDocs it is explained very well why your private array is not visible outside, and if you do not see him, neither are its methods

Comment: Your quote is not from the JavaDocs, it's from the Java Tutorials. And it's just a general description of access modifiers, it doesn't explain why an array's length is considered a member of its element class.

Comment: @MicheleLacorte array is clearly accessible outside as I shown. But it's length is not. And as far as I know the length property of any array is always visible.

Comment: Surely you instantiate an array of private class B , which has the length method , you instantiate an array of int will see that your code will work , alternatively declare the class B public and a.arr.length works !! @afzalex

Comment: I know if class B will be public, then array of this class will also be accessible, and I know private data could be accessed through some public method like **getter** functions. But Please try to understand. The question is if array is accessible, why it's length i.e. the length property which is always present in all array, and which seems to be public, is not accessible. I am not asking if there is other method to do this. The question is **WHY**

Answer (score 1):

Knows that the question is about accessing the `length` field. But, it was interesting for me to find that the `length` can be determined by enhanced-for-loop, not by making changes to access privileges or using reflection:

```
int length = 0;
for(Object o : a.arr) {
    length++;
}
```

Few interesting statements about arrays were:

[Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

[Array Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)

> An array's length is not part of its type.